# if a pointer variable is declared inside a loop, is it associated with the same memory address each pass of the loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, loops

If you have a variable, there is a memory address associated with that variable, and in the case of a pointer variable, the "value" of that memory address is a reference to the memory address that holds the actual data that the pointer points to.

so if I have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    char * a = (char*)malloc(20);
    printf("%p\r\n", &a);
    printf("%p\r\n", a);
}
```

the output should be something like:

```
    00999999
    04427310
    00999999
    0442ECF0
```

And as you can see,  the 1st and the 3rd memory address remain the same for the pointer variables declared during each pass of the loop, and my understanding is that this is so  because the previous variable went out of scope and the next available address is the same address.

Can this generalization be extended to all variables declared inside a loop or are there exceptions?

Comment: There's no guarantee, but generally yes, variables declared in a loop usually are allocated in the same place each iteration, since it's the simplest way for the compiler.

Comment: It's not *necessary* for a variable to have a memory address - if you hadn't printed `&a`, `a` could possibly have been kept in a register (and `x` most probably is in a register in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how a stack usually works. And this is independent of variable type. When the stack grows downwards it might look more or less like this

```
<top>
|                 |
+-----------------+
| argument1       |
| argument2       |
+-----------------+
| return address  |
+-----------------+
| saved register1 |
| saved register2 |
+-----------------+
| local variable1 | <- base register
| local variable2 |
| x               |
| a               |
|                 | <- stack pointer
<bottom>
```

The compiler assigns space on the stack to each variable relative to some base register. When the scope of the loop ends, the space for `a` effectively becomes "free" and can be reused.

If there's a second loop later or some other nested scope

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    char * a = (char*)malloc(20);
    printf("%p\r\n", &a);
    printf("%p\r\n", a);
}
...
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    char * b = (char*)malloc(20);
    printf("%p\r\n", &b);
    printf("%p\r\n", b);
}
```

`b` might reuse the space previously occupied by `a`, since it is not needed anymore for a. This all depends on how the compiler optimizes the space on the stack.

This is how it works for compiled C like languages at least. There are other memory models as well, of course.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't generalize this, and it's not guaranteed the memory for `a` (the pointer, not what it points to) will be the same on each iteration. In this case, the memory is reused, it's likely it will always be the same, but there's no guarantee whatsoever.

Also note that you have a memory leak.